# Kernel of bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

It is written in book, I read: **kernel of bilinear form is space consisting of vectors $y$, such:**

$$Ker(\alpha)=\{y\in V:\alpha(x,y)=0,\ \forall x\in V\}$$
Nice I get it, but then it is said, that **definition on top is equal to:**

$$Ker(\alpha)=\{y\in V:\alpha(e_i,y)=0,\ i=1,...,n\},$$
where $e_1,..e_n$ are basis vectors. That is the part I don't understand. I think, that we can transform definition using linear properties of $\alpha$:
$$x=x_1e_1 + ... + x_ne_n\\
Ker(\alpha)=\{y\in V:x_1\alpha(e_1,y)+..+x_n\alpha(e_n,y)=0,\ i=1,...,n, \ \forall x\in V\}$$

So please, how are these definitions equivalent?
Thank you!

Comment: If $\alpha\left(x,y\right) = 0$ for all $x$, then clearly $\alpha\left(e_i,y\right) = 0$ for all $i$ (just set $x = e_i$). Conversely, if $\alpha\left(e_i,y\right) = 0$ for all $i$, then $\alpha\left(x,y\right) = 0$ for all $x$, because writing $x $ as $\sum_i x_i e_i$ leads to $\alpha\left(x,y\right) = \alpha\left(\sum_i x_i e_i, y\right) = \sum_i x_i \underbrace{\alpha\left(e_i,y\right)}_{=0} = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof that the Ker of 1st definition is contained in second: If $y\in Ker(\alpha)$ then $\alpha(x,y)=0$ for each $x\in V$. It is obvious that basis vectors are in $V$ so $\alpha(e_i,y)=0$.

Proof that the Ker of 2nd definition is contained in the first: If $\alpha(e_i,y)=0$ and we take any $x\in V$ we have

$$x=\sum \lambda_i e_i$$

therefore
$$\alpha(x,y)=\sum\lambda_i\alpha(e_i,y)=0$$

*Remark*: In fact, there is no need $\{e_i\}$ to be a basis. They suffice to be a generators system of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ker_1(\alpha)$ be the first definition and $\ker_2(\alpha)$ be the second. We want to prove that $\ker_1(\alpha) = \ker_2(\alpha)$. It is clear that $\ker_1(\alpha)\subseteq \ker_2(\alpha)$. Now let $y \in \ker_2(\alpha)$. Let $x \in V$ be an arbitrary vector. Write $x = \sum_i x_ie_i$. Then: $$\alpha(x,y) = \alpha\left(\sum_ix_ie_i,y\right) = \sum_ix_i\alpha(e_i,y) = \sum_ix_i\cdot 0 = 0,$$ hence $y \in \ker_1(\alpha)$. So $\ker_1(\alpha) = \ker_2(\alpha)$ and the definitions are equivalent.